# ansible Jinja2 template loop for hosts with a var defined

Tags: jinja2, ansible

hosts

```
[mesosSandbox]
mesos1-01d.chalybs.net zoo_id=1
mesos1-02d.chalybs.net zoo_id=2
mesos1-03d.chalybs.net zoo_id=3
mesos1-04d.chalybs.net
mesos1-05d.chalybs.net
```

I have a template that generates the zookeeper zoo.cfg

```
{% for server in groups[cluster] %}
    server.{{loop.index}}={{server}}:2888:3888
{% endfor %}
```

Is there a way to add an `if zoo_id is defined` to this loop or can I generate a list via a task in the playbook?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ansible's `if var is defined` syntax is derived from jinja. You should be able to check for zoo id right in the loop:

```
{% for server in groups[cluster] %}
    {% if hostvars[server].zoo_id is defined %}
        server.{{loop.index}}={{server}}:2888:3888
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I can't say whether this will compile/run without seeing more of your playbook, but assuming the loop in your question works as is, this will allow you to filter on whether `zoo_id` is defined.

Comment: `zoo_id` refers to a variable for the current host (probably the one where the configuration is being deployed). If you want to access the right one, you need to use `hostvars[server].zoo_id` (and MAYBE load delegate facts before that, not sure it's needed when vars are defined in inventory)

Answer (score 2):

Ansible's template syntax is Jinja2, so you can use it right away.

Also, you need to access `zoo_id` for the target host using `hostvars` array.

```
{% for server in groups[cluster] %}
    {% if hostvars[server].zoo_id is defined %}
        server.{{loop.index}}={{server}}:2888:3888
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

You *may* need to load delegate facts before being able to access hostvars, but I believe it's not needed if you need to access anything defined directly in the inventory.